# WordPress admin slow speed problem after installing WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce

It is due to the request for api from the WooCommerce site, which can be solved by adding the following filters. Tested in wp version 6.0.3

```
add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_themes', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return true;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_product_data', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return ["fa_IR" => ["body"=>"{}"]];
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_onboarding_themes', function ($themes) {

   if(!is_array($themes))
   {
    $themes=[];
   }
   return $themes;
}, 10, 2);
```

That in the above code fa_IR is local wordpress.

By adding the above filters, the speed increases a lot

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_themes', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return true;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_product_data', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return ["fa_IR" => ["body"=>"{}"]];
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_onboarding_themes', function ($themes) {

   if(!is_array($themes))
   {
    $themes=[];
   }
   return $themes;
}, 10, 2);
```